# what is the relation between stlport.5.2.dll and Visual C++?? Do I need stlport for my program to run?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, stlport

I'm trying to write a simple hello world program in visual c++ using visual studio 2010 prof.
Im getting the following error after successful build.

```
System Error:
Application couldn't start because stlport.5.2.dll is missing
```

When I searched about it it is an open source project. So what is the link between these two? The only thing I changed from default VS installation is importing settings from other machine which is main build machine for our company.

Here is what I did:
1. Create an empty project.
2. Added a source file Main.cpp with hello world line.
3. F7
4. Ctrl+F5

Now I'm getting above error

Comment: Link with `/VERBOSE` and the linker will show you exactly why you get a dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to run devend.exe /ResetAddin

there shouldn't be any problem.

make sure you create a simple empty project and not some kind of pre-defind project that loads other components by default.
(win32 console application)

Also - search you project's external dependencies.. remove any h file that is there...

Comment: No Dani..still same problem :( I can't understand why this is happening. Before dumpin those settings it wasn't there. How can I reset settings to defaults??

Answer (score 0):

Our Organization uses STLPort as the standard C++ library. STLPort is an open source implementation of standard library for C++. So my Visual studio settings are modified such that any project uses stlport as the standard library and it is dynamically linked.

So we can either:

1. Put StlPort.X.X.dll in the directory where the executable is residing.
   OR
2. Remove the settings carefully to make your project to use default standard library provided by Microssoft SDK.